# Some questions about "ptr" in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm, mov

When I wrote
`mov edx, dword ptr[variable]`
It means pass the value of the variable to **edx**. However, when I wrote
`mov mm0, sword ptr[edx]`
It means pass the value pointed to by **edx** to **mm0**.

I want to know why the same code pattern have difference behaviors.

Comment: It's not different.  The symbol `variable` is a link-time-constant address, so you can use it in an addressing mode.  Just like `edx` can hold a non-constant address.  (BTW, MMX is basically obsolete with x86-64 which guarantees SSE2, and 32-bit pointers are also not normal for 64-bit code.)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [x86 Assembly pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43769467) - does that answer your question?  Or maybe [Why in NASM do we have to use square brackets (\[ \]) to MOV to memory location?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49534661) - it's simpler in NASM, a symbol name like `variable` consistently works as an address, never implicitly dereferenced, just like a C `char variable[]`.  MASM's design is super weird

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. There are some concepts in your answer that I don't understand very deeply. I think I should systematically learn assembly language.